# Python Zen - (only) one way to do it

Tags: python, zen-of-python

This question might be sound subjective, but as "the Zen" says, there is (nearly always) one way to preferred, it shouldn't be subjective at the end.

What way is the better one?

```
[i.something() for i in l]
map(operator.methodcaller('something'), l)
map(lambda x: x.something(), l)
```

(1) is (IMO) very clear, but in many answers, `map()` is used. And if we do so, there is nearly equal readability between (2) and (3) (IMO, at least).

The same counts for many other tasks, but I have chosen this one, as it can stand for all of similiar ones.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `.something()` does not modify `i` in any way?

Comment: Always list comprehension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Simple is better than complex.
- Readability counts.

Both are clear arguments for `[i.something() for i in l]`.

This assumes that `.something()` doesn't mutate `i`, and that you're on Python 2.

Comment: So, if that function mutates, which shall be preferred?

Comment: @thefourtheye: None of the above. In that case, an explicit `for` loop would be best: `for item in l: item.something()`. Using list comprehensions or `map`s for side effects is ugly.

Comment: And the list comprehension is better than the explicit for loop if you want to have a list of the return values. Corollary: methods should either mutate an instance or return something useful, doing both in one method is less good.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Right, this is why I made that assumption. But you never know...